# Ensuring file download from web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, download

We have a website where users pay for download access to a given document, and so we need to ensure the download can be successfully executed.

Our download action looks like this:

```
send_data generate_document(), 
    filename: "yourfile.pdf",
    type: "application/pdf",
    disposition: "attachment"
```

...and it works perfectly fine on all the browsers I've tested.

However, I often see download pages with prompts similar to the following:

> "If your file doesn't download automatically, click this link."

What's the reason for those prompts? Why would downloads fail initially, and what happens differently when users click the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most of the cases it's for very old browsers (at least that's what I was told by my colleague). Also some websites implement this using JS, those who don't have it enabled for some reason, can't see the download.

When user clicks a link, he explicitly directs browser to that location, such actions usually should work everywhere.